# Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyResponse Object

Tags: google-calendar-api

**I am using freebusy api Oauth2 service account** am getting the following result. Always busy array is coming empty even though I created multiple events on my calendar. what would be the problem

### MyCode:

```
 $items_arr = [
        "xxxxx.com_3434343434xxxxxgb6oqjge1g6cpjed9g74@resource.calendar.google.com"
    ,
        "xxxxx.com_454544dfdfv7v9q6gb6cpjacpg6kp36dpo6c@resource.calendar.google.com"

    ];

    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=meeting-room-app-4423234xx-5f984f6e1xew3634ds3rdtsdeeqdfe.json');
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);


    $fnlItems=[];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($items_arr); $i++) {

        $item = new Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequestItem();
        $item->setId($items_arr[$i]);

        array_push($fnlItems, $item);
    }


    $timezone = "IST";
    $freebusy_req = new Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequest();
    $freebusy_req->setTimeMin(date(DateTime::ATOM, strtotime('2020-01-01T08:00:00.000Z')));
    $freebusy_req->setTimeMax(date(DateTime::ATOM, strtotime('2020-01-31T17:00:00.000Z')));
    $freebusy_req->setTimeZone($timezone);
    $freebusy_req->setCalendarExpansionMax(10);
    $freebusy_req->setGroupExpansionMax(10);

    //$item='';
    $fnlItems=[];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($items_arr); $i++) {
        $item = new Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequestItem();
        $item->setId($items_arr[$i]);
        array_push($fnlItems, $item);
    }
    $freebusy_req->setItems($fnlItems);
    $results = $service->freebusy->query($freebusy_req);

    // $response = $sqladmin->instances
    //     ->listInstances('meeting-room-app-265703')->getItems();

    print_r($results); die;
```

### Below is the result I am getting:

```
Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyResponse Object
(
    [calendarsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyCalendar
    [calendarsDataType:protected] => map`enter code here`
    [groupsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyGroup
    [groupsDataType:protected] => map
    [kind] => calendar#freeBusy
    [timeMax] => 2020-01-31T18:29:59.000Z
    [timeMin] => 2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
            [calendars] => Array
                (
                    [xxxxx.com_188dql9c1ap8ssdqhvdfdsds1gb7ddr55aufhr726gb@resource.calendar.google.com] => Array
                        (
                            [errors] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [domain] => global
                                            [reason] => notFound
                                        )

                                )

                            [busy] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
```

Comment: I created multiple events in my google calendar with status busy also.

Comment: Are the calendars with the given IDs shared with the service account?